# How does controller, controllerGrip, and hand communicate with XR device buttons in threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js, virtual-reality, webxr

(May 15 2023) In this [example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webxr_xr_dragging.html) from threejs, the controllers are defined using these codes:

```
// controllers

controller1 = renderer.xr.getController( 0 );
controller1.addEventListener( 'selectstart', onSelectStart );
controller1.addEventListener( 'selectend', onSelectEnd );
scene.add( controller1 );

controller2 = renderer.xr.getController( 1 );
controller2.addEventListener( 'selectstart', onSelectStart );
controller2.addEventListener( 'selectend', onSelectEnd );
scene.add( controller2 );

const controllerModelFactory = new XRControllerModelFactory();

controllerGrip1 = renderer.xr.getControllerGrip( 0 );
controllerGrip1.add( controllerModelFactory.createControllerModel( controllerGrip1 ) );
scene.add( controllerGrip1 );

controllerGrip2 = renderer.xr.getControllerGrip( 1 );
controllerGrip2.add( controllerModelFactory.createControllerModel( controllerGrip2 ) );
scene.add( controllerGrip2 );
```

According to the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=webgl#api/en/renderers/webxr/WebXRManager) from threejs, both `renderer.xr.getController` and `renderer.xr.getControllerGrip` returns a `THREE.Group`.

> .getController ( index : Integer ) : Group
> index — The index of the controller.
>
> Returns a Group representing the so called target ray space of the XR controller. Use this space for visualizing 3D objects that support the user in pointing tasks like UI interaction.
>
> .getControllerGrip ( index : Integer ) : Group
> index — The index of the controller.
>
> Returns a Group representing the so called grip space of the XR controller. Use this space if the user is going to hold other 3D objects like a lightsaber.
>
> Note: If you want to show something in the user's hand AND offer a pointing ray at the same time, you'll want to attached the handheld object to the group returned by .getControllerGrip() and the ray to the group returned by .getController(). The idea is to have two different groups in two different coordinate spaces for the same WebXR controller.
>
> .getHand ( index : Integer ) : Group
> index — The index of the controller.
>
> Returns a Group representing the so called hand or joint space of the XR controller. Use this space for visualizing the user's hands when no physical controllers are used.

My question is, if `controller1/2` and `controllerGrip1/2` are all just instances of `Group`, how does the `controller1.addEventListener( 'selectstart', onSelectStart );` work so that the code is able respond to buttons? And what is the difference between controller and controllerGrip and hands? It seems by only adding event listeners to the controller, the code also respond to hand pinch, so why is this?